# How to display number of results that would show in a contextually filtered view

Tags: views

I have a view which has some contextual filters (not exposed) which limit the view results so they are only shown to the page author. I would like to show other users how many (total) results there are in the view.
I thought I could do that with a Global Results Summary under No Results Behavior, but that only shows results AFTER the contextual filter has been applied.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add an Attachment to the View. You can control the Access and change the filters.